# Capybara - Overriding a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have the following interesting scenario:

The test system, in my case BogusGateway of ActiveMerchant requires credit card of a "bogus" type in order to be valid.  Naturally, this is not one of the options that I present to the user.

In my request spec, I'm trying to override the original value for visa with "bogus", however I'm not clear on how it's done.  I've tried something like that, but no lucK:

```
# setting the value for the visa card to be 'bogus'
find(:xpath, "//input[@id='billing_account_card_type_visa']").set "bogus"

# then clicking on the radio button...
choose "billing_account_card_type_visa"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user can't choose that option, how is Capybara supposed to do it?

Instead of mimicking a user action which can't be performed, just make the request with the invalid parameters:

`post "/my_billing_path", :billing_account => { :card_type => "bogus }`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use capybara's [`fill_in`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions%3afill_in) and [`choose`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#choose-instance_method) methods:

```
fill_in("billing_acount_card_type_visa", :with => "bogus")
choose("billing_account_card_type_visa")
```

Comment: I believe this won't work, because fill_in method is only for text fields/areas.  Here we are dealing with radio buttons, hence using "choose" method.

Comment: Oh I see. Not really sure then, maybe @zetetic's answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following numbers to get through the validation and test a successful transaction using capybara and the bogus gateway:

- VISA = 4111111111111111
- MASTERCARD = 5500000000000004
- AMEX = 340000000000009
- DISCOVERY = 6011000000000004